# Form Cancel Button Issue

Tags: asp.net, html, forms

I have a working form for a mobile site. I changed the cancel button to an image style of button and now the form validation pops up when click it in a mobile browser. After dismissing the validation message the site returns to the previous page.  The form was not being validated when the user clicked the cancel button but when I switched the type from "button" to "image" the form gets validated and I can't figure out why.

Before:

```
<pre>
    input type="button" onclick="history.back();" value="Cancel"
</pre>
```

After:

```
<pre>
    input type="image" onclick="history.back();"
    src="images/Mobile_Form_Button_01_Cancel.png"

</pre>
```

Comment: Seems you forgot to ask your `question` !!!

Comment: @zucchini: Please edit your question with your question :) and you can delete your comment

Comment: I think the word “why” was an indirect question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="image" />
```

Actually is a 'submit' button as an image. More info [here (W3C Schools)](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp).

To make it work, change it back to `<input type="button" />` and style it using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it happens is that inside a `form` element, [`input type=image`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1) acts as a submit button of a special kind. This means that any scripted or HTML-defined validation will take place by default. In contract, an `input type=button` element creates a button that has no default action; any action must be scripted. (This often makes it a poor choice in static HTML: when scripting is disabled in the browser, the button will sit there and do nothing, no matter how much you click on it.)

There are different ways to avoid this. One way is to add `return false` at the end of the `onclick` code, preventing the default action. Another is to use `input type=button` or `button` and style it according to your preferences. Yet another is to have just an `img` element with `onclick` attribute (but preferably as generated by JavaScript).

The best option is to remove the element. From the usability point of view, you should not duplicate browser functionality – unless you are writing an HTML5 application rather than a web page.